# How can I parse SVG server side with XML Serializer?

Tags: c#, xml, svg, .net-core

I've read tons and tons of forum post. Most people either want to convert SVG to image and save it, or end up getting really messy with XML descendants and walking the XML dom manually. I'm trying to do what I always do in JSON and create .Net objects like this

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "svg", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class SvgXml
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "rect", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
   public Rect Rect { get; set; }
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "defs", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
   public Defs Defs { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
   public string Id { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
   public string Xmlns { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
   public string Version { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "width")]
   public string Width { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "height")]
   public string Height { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xlink", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
   public string Xlink { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "style")]
   public string Style { get; set; }
}

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SvgXml), new XmlRootAttribute("svg"));
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
```

But it doesn't work, I get an error.

```
{"<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> was not expected."}
```

I'm trying to get a strongly typed object so I can do `SvgXml.Children.First()`. Any ideas? Here is a sample of my SVG:

```
<svg id="Model" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500"      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background-color: blue;">
  <rect id="shape-0" width="100" height="100" fill="green" class="draggable" pointer-events="all" x="211" y="105"></rect>
  <defs id="SvgjsDefs1001"></defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you use that constructor for XmlSerializer? (as code works fine with just regular `XmlSerializer(type)` constructor)

Comment: I saw example somewhere.. Thanks! That fixed that error.. but now im using svg.js with the selext and resize plugins..and every time i create a rectangle it makes a new SVG and some random elipses! I guess i will have to make another question

Comment: For anyone else who sees this.  You also need to turn each item in SVG class to a list.. like List<rect> and List<g> and even then you will get a list of all shapes